# I tried to put an icon over an image but the icon shows at the right end of the screen

Tags: css, css-position

I want to put the icon at the bottom right corner of the image.

[image]

```css
.side {
  position: relative;
}

.side img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.side i {
  background-color: rgb(82, 79, 79);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="side">
  <img class="image" src="images/bread.JPG">
  <i class="fa fa-thin fa-plus"></i>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you set display:'block', the width of the element will be 100%, you should set its display to "inline-block"

```css
.side {
  position: relative;
}

.side img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.side i {
  background-color: rgb(82, 79, 79);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="side">
  <img class="image" src="images/bread.JPG">
  <i class="fa fa-thin fa-plus"></i>
</aside>
```